# Scala function => as parameter

Tags: scala

Could anybody kindly explain to me why the following

```
  /**
   * Returns a set transformed by applying `f` to each element of `s`.
   */
    def map(s: Set, f: Int => Int): Set = x => exists(s, y => f(y) == x)
```

is not equivalent to

```
    def map(s: Set, f: Int => Int): Set = x => exists(s, f(x))
```

where "exists" is a function that returns whether there exists a bounded integer within `s`(the first argument) that satisfies `p`(the second argument).

Why do you need to specify "y => f(y) == x"? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`exists`'s second argument has the type `Int => Boolean` (right?), in other words, it expects a function from `Int` to `Boolean`. Now, `f(x)` doesn't conform to that type - it has the type `Int`. So - `y => f(y) == x` creates a function with the correct type, that returns true if its input equals `x`.

If the excess characters bug you - you can also shorten it a bit using the *anonymous argument* '_':

```
def map(s: Set, f: Int => Int): Set = x => exists(s, f(_) == x)
```

Comment: My guess is that the OP was confused by thinking about `x => exists(s, _ == f(x))` which type checks (unfortunately, since `f` hasn't the most general type), but does the wrong thing.